# Webpage shows uneven margin on the right after adding CSS in div

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which works finely as expected until I add a grey background div with the following code:

```
.grey-div{
  padding: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1ae;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b1b1ae;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

This element when added creates a uneven margin as shown in [this image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbL3p.png)
,
When I remove the code, everything gets fixed.
Also this only happens on phone, and there is no horizontal scrollbar even if the grey div creates extra space in the right side, what is this called?

Comment: I guess only the grey div is insufficient to determine how the page is being affected, we need the code of your page to help you

Comment: @Andus the code is pretty basic, no extra JS, CSS, or anything except the width of the parent elements and the coloring